# Unknown type error in xaml with class derived from ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Based on this example at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx), I created a "non-generic custom collection class that derives from ObservableCollection, and constrains it to a specific type." This is used as the ItemsSource property of a listview control. This all works perfectly and the xaml design view displays the sample data I loaded into the custom collection class.

The problem occurs when I try to build the project; I get this error: "Error 1 Unknown type 'ThreadCollection' in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:Messaging_2._0;assembly=Messaging 2.0.WindowsPhone, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' C:\Users\Wesley\Source\Repos\Messenging 2.0\Messaging 2.0\Messaging 2.0\Messaging 2.0.WindowsPhone\MainPage.xaml 14 10 Messaging 2.0.WindowsPhone.

This error originates from the line `<c:ThreadCollection x:Key="MainThreadCollection"/>` of the xaml code below.

```
<Page
x:Class="Messaging_2._0.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Messaging_2._0"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:c="clr-namespace:Messaging_2._0"

mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

<Page.Resources>
    <c:ThreadCollection x:Key="MainThreadCollection"/>
</Page.Resources>
<The code for the listview control is here, I haven't included it because it works as I expect.>
```

Here is the C# code behind referenced by the xaml:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234238

namespace Messaging_2._0
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public ThreadCollection MainThreadCollection = new ThreadCollection();

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked when this page is about to be displayed in a Frame.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">Event data that describes how this page was reached.
        /// This parameter is typically used to configure the page.</param>
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: Prepare page for display here.

            // TODO: If your application contains multiple pages, ensure that you are
            // handling the hardware Back button by registering for the
            // Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed event.
            // If you are using the NavigationHelper provided by some templates,
            // this event is handled for you.
        }

        private void AddThread(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MainThreadCollection.Add(new ThreadViewItem() { Name = "Tom Riddle", LatestMessage = "It worked!" });
        }
    }

    public class ThreadCollection : ObservableCollection<ThreadViewItem>
    {
        public ThreadCollection()
            : base()
        {
            Add(new ThreadViewItem() { Name = "Harry Potter", LatestMessage = "What's up?" });
        }
    }

    public class ThreadViewItem
    {
        public String Name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public String LatestMessage
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

Because the design view previews the message from Harry Potter correctly, I think the problem is relatively minor, I just can't figure out what it is exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would place the ThreadCollection in its own file (preferably ThreadCollection.cs) and place it in its own namespace, like **Messaging_2._0.Collections** or something similar. Then point the xmlns:c to that namespace.

That will ensure that your class isn't affected by the automatic code generation involved when coding XAML.

If it doesn't solve your issue, the error text might at least be more helpful.